# Comparing dataframes by their column name and observations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function to compare two dataframes, and to return `True` if equal, and `False` if the column name and observations are not equal.

```
def table_equal(A, B):
    var_names = sorted(A.columns)
    Y = A[var_names].copy()
    Y.sort_values(by=var_names, inplace=True)
    Y.set_index([list(range(0,len(Y)))], inplace=True)

    var_names2 = sorted(B.columns)
    Z = B[var_names2].copy()
    Z.sort_values(by=var_names, inplace=True)
    Z.set_index([list(range(0,len(Y)))], inplace=True)

    if Y.equals(Z):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Let's say I have an original table(A) that I want to compare other tables to.

```
a   b   c
x   1   hat
y   2   cat
z   3   bat
w   4   rat
```

My function works for almost all permutations of Table B, except for the following table, which is giving me `True` instead of `False`:

```
a   c   b
x   1   hat
y   2   cat
z   3   bat
w   4   rat
```

Is there some tweaking I have to do with my code?

Follow up question:

I want the 2 tables below to be True with same observations in the same variable.

```
    a   b   c
0   x   1   hat
1   y   2   cat
2   z   3   bat
3   w   4   rat

    c   b   a
6   rat 4   w
3   hat 1   x
1   bat 3   z
9   cat 2   y
```

From piRSquared's solution, the code works, but how do I ignore having the rows being exactly the same in each table as long as the observations are the same?

Comment: For the table comparison that fails, have you tried printing out the computed values of `Y` and `Z` to see if they are what you think they should be? Seems like the same basic approach could be taken to verify which intermediate step(s) aren't working the way you think (which ultimately leads to one of them not being what you thought).

Comment: Shouldn't the `Z.sort_values(by=var_names, inplace=True)` be `Z.sort_values(by=var_names2, inplace=True)`?

Comment: Try: `if Y.reset_index(drop=True).equals(Z.reset_index(drop=True))` because sort does not alter the index, and comparisons are done by index.

Comment: It should be var_names2.  thanks for catching that. Unfortunately, that and the Y.set_index still produces the wrong thing.  It looks like every step looks right to me, but for some reason, it's still returning true instead of false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**
Clearly:

```
A.equals(B)

False
```

**Solution**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.align`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html)

Rewrite your function...

```
def table_equal(A, B):
    X, Y = A.align(B)
    return (X.values == Y.values).all()

table_equal(A, B)

False
```

---

**Explanation**
`align` will return two dataframes whose columns and indices are the same.

```
A.align(B)

(
       a  b    c
    0  x  1  hat
    1  y  2  cat
    2  z  3  bat
    3  w  4  rat,

       a    b  c
    0  x  hat  1
    1  y  cat  2
    2  z  bat  3
    3  w  rat  4
)
```

Since the indices are aligned, we can compare the `values` attributes to see if they are all the same.  In this case, they are not.

Comment: Amazingly Simple. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to ignore comparing the indices, and just the column values ['a','b','c'] ?  For example, I don't care if table A has indices 0,1,2,3 or 6,7,8,9

Comment: Yes, use `A.align(B, axis=1)`

Comment: Ah.  So  adding the extra axis =1 this is going against what I originally had intended this function to production.  I don't necessarily care if the row values are exactly the same in Table A and B.  I just need the column Variable and observations to share the same values.  I originally decided to sort them in my original function because I couldn't' figure out a better way to do this.

Comment: nvm. I combined both my solution and yours and it worked out.  Thanks